# Android Parcelable Takes Up More Memory

Tags: java, android, memory, parcelable, parcel

The question is simple, if I make an object parcelable, and put it into a bundle and create a fragment using the bundle. Does the object get cloned or is it referenced.

The context.

I have got an object stored/referenced in an ArrayList. Depending on the type of object in the ArrayList (polymorphism is used). I create a fragment suitable for dealing with it.

I need to also pass this object to the fragment. The fragment is used within a custom view pager. I do not wish to have duplicate objects and it seems to me parcelable clones objects.

Another method is to pass the index of the object in the ArrayList. and then get a reference to the arraylist from the fragment using getActivity().myList.get(Integer passed to ). But it doesn't seem very safe to me (ArrayList contents may change, although I simply delete everything and start again). I have also read, that you should avoid passing arguments to a fragments constructor as it may be recreated using the default no-args constructor.

(Although I'm currently destroying any recreated fragments as there are some strange problem with reattaching to the correct view, another post).

New sub-question: is there a way to pass a value by reference to a fragment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is simple, if I make an object parcelable, and put it into a bundle and create a fragment using the bundle. Does the object get cloned or is it referenced.

It may get cloned, if not immediately, at other points in time (e.g., when the fragment's arguments `Bundle` is included in the instance state).

> I have also read, that you should avoid passing arguments to a fragments constructor as it may be recreated using the default no-args constructor.

Correct.

> Another method is to pass the index of the object in the ArrayList. and then get a reference to the arraylist from the fragment using getActivity().myList.get(Integer passed to ). But it doesnt seem very safe to me (ArrayList contents may change, although I simply delete everything and start again).

Don't use an `ArrayList`. Use a `HashMap` with a durable key. Pass the key to the fragment. Have the fragment get the data via the key. Make sure anyone deleting this object (and thereby removing it from the `HashMap`) does so only when this fragment does not exist, or notifies this fragment so it knows how to handle this scenario.

Comment: That was the way I was previously handling it. just would have prefered to have done something like

new ArrayList
for i < ArrayList
addTab(ArrayList.get(i))

ArrayList=null

And have the fragments be the only area where a reference is held. But it might not make sense in the future. So I suppose ill use a hashmap.

Although the question still stands, Is there a better way to pass a reference to a fragment.

Thanks for the answer, Ill leave it open for another day,  just incase someone else wants to add something.

Comment: I have tried this method however once the phone is rotated, the fragments call onCreate sooner than the activity. And so the object arnt yet initialised.